# iOS: UICollectionView implementation of viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind bombing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this method to supply a simple dumb header for UICollectionView sections:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *header = nil;

    NSString *sectionTitle;
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            sectionTitle = @"One";
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionTitle = @"Two";
            break;
        case 2:
            sectionTitle = @"Thre";
            break;
        case 3:
            sectionTitle = @"Four";
            break;
    }

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                    withReuseIdentifier:@"headerView"
                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        sectionLabel.text = sectionTitle;
        [self.rosterCollectionView addSubview:sectionLabel];
    }


    return header;
}
```

It bombs on the `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind` call with:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UICollectionView.m:3117`

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` to register your class/nib before use dequeue method

Comment: What if it's just a `UIView` I've created in code? It's a stupid simple view with a `UILabel`.

Comment: just subclass UIView and register. doc link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier: